# Interop: are struct packing alignment defaults the same for C# and unmanaged C++ on a given platform?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, uwp

Or do I need to explicitly specify alignment in each to assure a match? Both the C# and unmanaged C code are built on the same system (either VS IDE or MSBuild).

Comment: Why wouldn't you always want to be explicit?  Doing so removes all doubt.

Comment: Because one assumes the defaults are going to be those determined optimal for the general case by the compiler designers, whose judgment is probably better than mine.

Comment: I'd suggest explicitly telling the compiler what kind of `struct` layout and packing you want. That way you'll be sure that the result is the expected. Implementations may be different to other architectures (or even Operating Systems)

Comment: Interop in a UWP app is carefully obscured by the *language projection* built into the CLR.  On the C++ side it is done with the C++/CX extension or the C++/WinRT library.  Under the hood you are using COM to get the chunks of code to talk to each other.  It is all quite invisible, I'm not aware of a case where alignment caused trouble.  So keep moving, nothing much to worry about.

Comment: @Hans this sounds more like P/Invoke.

Comment: Yes, I'm using P/Invoke for C#/unmanaged C interop, there's no C++/CX

Answer (score 2):

Default packing sizes for [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8) and [C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/storage-and-alignment-of-structures?view=vs-2019).

The C article says that the default packing is governed by the `/Zp[n]` compiler switch option, which is set to 8 by default.

The C# article says that the Pack field controls the alignment of a type's fields in memory. By default, the value is 0, indicating the default packing size for the "current platform," whatever that means (read the article; the story there is a bit more complex than the C/C++ version).

Comment: I don't see where in the C# article it says that default is 8 though. It just happens to give examples where 8 works out to the same result as default (attribute set to 0).

Comment: @Stacklysm that's for C/C++ only.

Comment: That just says the structure -size- is 8 bytes, not that it's aligned to 8 bytes.